# About the input of quantum neural network in tensorflow quantum

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-quantum

I created a quantum neural network using tensorflow quantum，It's input is a tensor converted by circuit.About this input circuit，I found that if the parameters of the circuit are also specified by tensors, the quantum neural network cannot be trained.

**The circuit when using normal parameters can make the network train normally**

```
theta_g=1
blob_size = abs(1 - 4) / 5
spread_x = np.random.uniform(-blob_size, blob_size)
spread_y = np.random.uniform(-blob_size, blob_size)
angle = theta_g + spread_y
cir=cirq.Circuit(cirq.ry(-angle)(qubit), cirq.rx(-spread_x)(qubit))
discriminator_network(tfq.convert_to_tensor([cir]))
```

**But when I use the following code, the quantum neural network cannot be trained**

```
theta_g=tf.constant([1])
blob_size = abs(1 - 4) / 5
spread_x = np.random.uniform(-blob_size, blob_size)
spread_y = np.random.uniform(-blob_size, blob_size)
spred_x = tf.constant(spread_x)
spred_y = tf.constant(spread_y)
angle = theta_g + spread_y
cir=cirq.Circuit(cirq.ry(-angle)(qubit), cirq.rx(-spread_x)(qubit))
discriminator_network(tfq.convert_to_tensor([cir]))
```

** the disciminator_network**

```
def discriminator():
    theta = sympy.Symbol('theta')
    q_model = cirq.Circuit(cirq.ry(theta)(qubit))
    q_data_input = tf.keras.Input(
        shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.string)
    expectation = tfq.layers.PQC(q_model, cirq.Z(qubit))
    expectation_output = expectation(q_data_input)

    classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
    classifier_output = classifier(expectation_output)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=q_data_input, outputs=classifier_output)
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the trace of the error you are getting, I would say that *I think* the problem you are running into in the second snippet is that you have placed `tf.constant` objects into the placeholders of the `cirq.Circuit`. The reason your first example works is because cirq.Circuits know how to interpret values from np.float32 datatypes. Cirq does not know how to interpret values from tf.float32 (or any tf.dtypes.* for that matter).

TensorFlow Quantum's entry point to interface tensorflow datatypes with cirq.Circuit objects is via resolving the `sympy.Symbol` values inside of the circuits in tfq native operations (which you have done in creating the `tfq.layers.PQC`).

Does this help clear things up ?

-Michael